# Javascript - onclick, play sound, wait x seconds, load URL

Tags: javascript, html, audio, onclick

At the moment I have an image linked to a page with an onClick event to play a sound when clicked.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <audio id="audio1" src="SOUND.wav" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
</div>

<script> function EvalSound(soundobj) 
    { var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj); thissound.play(); } 
</script>

<a href="PAGE.php" onClick="EvalSound('audio1')"><img src="IMAGE.png"></a>
```

This works fine as is, but the sound is cut off by the page load. Assuming the "SOUND.wav" is 10 seconds long, how would I edit my code so that when the image is clicked, there is a 10 second pause while the sound plays, THEN it loads the page?

Thank you or your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code as follows:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <audio id="audio1" src="SOUND.wav" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
</div>

<script> function EvalSound(soundobj) 
    { var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj); thissound.play(); 
setTimeout( function() { window.location.href = 'PAGE.php'; }, 1000); } // change 1000 to whatever value you would want to wait in milliseconds.
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="EvalSound('audio1')"><img src="IMAGE.png"></a
```

>

Comment: Thank you, that worked great, but is there a way to append the timeout/window.location.href to the <a>? There may be multiple images that link to different pages with the same audio clip.

Comment: sure.  you can change your a tag to <a href="#" onClick="EvalSound('audio1'); setTimeout( function() { window.location.href = 'PAGE.php'; }, 1000);"> and remove the setTimeout from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Same as the answer before me, only I suggest you use the audio api to determine the duration of the sound and set it as the timeout.

Also, to change the url you could add it as an argument.

```
function EvalSoundAndRedirect(soundobj, url) {
    var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
    thissound.play();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = url;
    }, thissound.duration);
}
```

Using:

```
<a href="#" onClick="EvalSoundAndRedirect('audio1', 'PAGE.php')"><img src="IMAGE.png" /></a>
```

Comment: This would work fine also, except that the audio file has a bit of white noise at the end that I want to cut off. Setting the duration myself helps with that.